# Puppeteer how to use browser.newPage without waiting for the dom to load, or the default which is "load" -- simply open it instantly and move on

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have the following in my code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
{ 
    variableNames[i] = await browser.newPage();
    await variableNames[i].goto('https://www.Example.com/'+list[i], {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
}
```

which creates a large amount of tabs in 1 browser instance, this works. The problem is awaiting variableNames[i].goto takes too long.

What ends up happening is it relatively slowly opens page after page.
Open page, stay there until "domcontentloaded" then open the next page, and so on.

If I remove the await, it opens up instantly, but things start going haywire with errors

By default with no waitUntil option, it waits for "load" which is slower, the fastest is "domcontentloaded" but is still really slow, considering all i want to do is open a bunch of tabs with no waiting while keeping history of what variable owns what tab.

I basically don't want it to wait for anything, just enter the URL and done.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you need css/images/javascript to be loaded as well ?

Comment: @SélimAchour I already remove images, but since all the HTML I need is loaded in, i can't remove any javascript. Removing CSS also for some reason breaks the site. 

My problem is that i don't see an option to just open a tab, without having to use the default option or else of "waiting" until something happens

Comment: You have to wait for something. If you're not waiting for the goto, maybe wait for a selector.

Answer (score 0):

solution in case someone finds this:
`variableNames[i].goto('https://example/'+list[i]).catch(() => { });`
just add a catch block.